# Nested Volley Requests in Android Studio in single session connection

Tags: android, jquery, android-studio, url, android-volley

I want to extract data from an HTTPS site. but It's generating an access code for every new opening of the website. so I used volley for getting access code once and getting the result of https once but when I am making 2nd request to get the result, a new session is a creation that leads to a change of access code. Can I do this in a single request ? or is there any alternate way to do this?

```
   RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="https://jntukresults.edu.in/view-results-56736070.html";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        access_code=StringUtils.substringBetween(response, "&accessToken=\"+", ",true);");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),raju,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(stringRequest);

        String resultUrl="https://jntukresults.edu.in/results/res.php?ht=16FE1A0593&id=56736070&accessToken="+access_code;
        StringRequest stringRequest1=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, resultUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response2) {
                textView.setText(response2);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response2,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(stringRequest1);
```